# Historical background with Weber and Kronecker's Jugendtraum

Tags: mathematicians, hilbert, kronecker

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74073/the-first-complete-proof-of-the-kronecker-weber-theorem

I searched above link, and I was so interested about this post.

Today, I have a question about historical background of Kronecker's Jugendtraum. In particular, I want to know the relationship with Heinrich Martin Weber and Kronecker's Jugendtraum.

I know that Weber finally missed his chance to disprove Hilbert's claim in Hilbert's 12th problem because of overlooking precisely the possibility of choosing different signs.

I was googling to know about this, then I found "Elliptic functions According to Eisenstein and Kronecker" and "On the History of Hilbert's Twelfth problem A comedy or errors" etc.
I read them precisely but I can't understand Weber's work in Kronecker Jugendtraum and history of Kronecker's Jugendtraum.

So, I would like to get your help.

Answer (score 1):

The history is described in the book of Serge Vladut,
Kronecker's Jugendtraum and modular functions, Overseas Publishers Assoc., 1991.